# Wrong model given by Z3 for sequence

Tags: z3

I put the following code in https://rise4fun.com/Z3/

```
(declare-const s (Seq Int))
(declare-const t1 (Seq Int))
(declare-const t2 (Seq Int))
(declare-const n Int)

(assert (= (seq.len s) n))
(assert (>= n 3))
(assert (= (seq.extract s 0 (- n 1)) t1))
(assert (= (seq.extract s 1 (- n 1)) t2))
(assert (= t1 t2))
;;(assert (not (= (seq.at s 0) (seq.at s (- n 1)))))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

The result is

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun s () (Seq Int)
    (seq.++ (seq.unit 14) (seq.++ (seq.unit 16) (seq.unit 18))))
  (define-fun t2 () (Seq Int)
    (seq.++ (seq.unit 16) (seq.unit 18)))
  (define-fun n () Int
    3)
  (define-fun t1 () (Seq Int)
    (seq.++ (seq.unit 16) (seq.unit 18)))
)
```

This model is wrong. `(seq.extract s 0 (- n 1))` should be `[14; 16]` instead of `[16; 18]`.

Did I misunderstand anything or it is a mistake of Z3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequence logic has seen a lot of changes in z3, lots of bug fixes since the rise4fun version of z3 was released. With a recent build, I get:

```
sat
(model
  (define-fun s () (Seq Int)
    (seq.++ (seq.unit 4) (seq.unit 4) (seq.unit 4)))
  (define-fun t2 () (Seq Int)
    (seq.++ (seq.unit 4) (seq.unit 4)))
  (define-fun t1 () (Seq Int)
    (seq.++ (seq.unit 4) (seq.unit 4)))
  (define-fun n () Int
    3)
)
```

which looks correct to me.

Long story short: The version of z3 at rise4fun is simply too old for this problem and is buggy. See if you can download a more recent version (or even a nightly build) from https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases